# Windows Xaml IconElement overview

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I'm currently working on a Windows 8.1 App. I want to set the Icon on an AppBarButton. There are a lot of Icons and i would like have an overview. Is there any or do i have to make one by myself? I would like to have an overview over the Icons and not only the name within Intellisense.

```
        <AppBarButton x:Name="btnTest" Icon="Accept" Label="Test" />
```

Comment: Look into properties in you commandbar. In the *common* section you have primary and secondary commands. Just click button with three dots ... and in the opened window you can add buttons with creator where you can see every available icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into properties in you commandbar. In the common section you have primary and secondary commands. Just click button with three dots ... and in the opened window you can add buttons with creator where you can see every available icon.